# OpenBSD window managers

Tags: window-managers, openbsd

I am getting started with OpenBSD (using VirtualBox) and would like to know how one can try and choose between the window managers FVWM, TWM and CWM.

In order to run a specific window manager:
Is there some configuration file to modify?
Or some specific command to run?

There is a lot of information on the net, but nothing clear in what I read.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to run X on OpenBSD is with the `xenodm` display manager. Enable it at boot :

```
# rcctl enable xenodm
# rcctl start xenodm
```

After that, you can customize your X session by creating a `$HOME/.xsession` script to start your window manager. Example with FVWM :

```
export ENV=$HOME/.kshrc
exec fvwm
```

See [xinit manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/xinit) and [FAQ for the X Widnow System](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html).